# How do I join the args of a function to form a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain a string from the attributes of the `changegame` function in order to change the status of a bot i'm developing.

````
async def changegame(*game_chosen: str):
    """Changes the game the bot is playing"""
    game_str = discord.Game(name=game_chosen)
    try:
        await bot.change_status(game=game_str, idle=False)
        await bot.say("```Game correctly changed to {0}```".format(game_chosen))
````

This does not result in the string being recognized but in this:

`Game correctly changed to ('Test', 'string', '123')`

Comment: What do you want it to do? Concatenate them?

Comment: What is `async def... *game_chosen: str`? That doesn't look like standard Python (which is what you tagged).

Comment: Though there is a simple answer, most probably you should be passing a single name to `changegame`, not multiple arguments. Where do you call that function?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yes exactly

Comment: @AmiTavory i have `import asincio` from discord.py

Comment: @spectras no because if I change the name to League Of Legends it only shows League and ignores the rest

Comment: The answers are right but @spectras is correct. If you want them called as one argument, why even define it to take multiple? What is the difference between the arguments if you're just going to run them together as one?

Comment: @margobra8 How are you calling the function that it creates this problem?

Comment: @margobra8> because at some point, before, you split the name into a list of three strings. That's what you should prevent. Passing the list around and glueing it together everywhere you use it is much more cumbersome than just fixing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve your initial issue, try a simple join:

```
' '.join(map(str, game_chosen))
```

However, your bigger problem is:

```
game_str = discord.Game(name=game_chosen)
```

Here you are passing a *tuple* to `discord.Game`, are you sure this is right? If you want to call your initial function like this: `changegame("League of Legends")`, then you need to fix your function definition:

```
async def changegame(game_chosen: str)
```

I suspect this is what you are actually trying to do.